# If you configure android Room, removing the safe-room configuration will result in a packaging error

Tags: android, android-room

My gradle configuration:

[image]

I don't want the saferoom configuration, comment it out, but packing or installing it straight would get an error, not if it wasn't commented out

[image]

> List of apks:
>
> [0] 'E:\workspace\m2\juancash2\10.1\2.0.0\1\juancash\app\build\outputs\apk\has\debug\dev-v20221215-04171658-has-debug.apk'
> Installation failed due to: 'INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113'

I tried to directly remove all references about the configuration of room, but I still reported this error.

Comment: SafeRoom has been discontinued for years, and SQLCipher for Android has Room compatibility. Your error suggests that there is some problem between what CPU architectures SQLCipher for Android supports and what hardware you are trying to run your app on.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)

Comment: thank you， I have tried to add it：   abiFilters 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64', 'mips', 'mips64'， but I still have the same problem